# Manual reference counting in Objective-C: should I release a NSString property?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, reference-counting

The project is using Manual Reference Counting.

In my AppDelegate.h file I have a property of NSString:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* apiId;
```

In my AppDelegate.m file I am setting the property like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    self.apiId = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    return YES;
}
```

Later in the dealloc of my AppDelegate.m method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_apiId release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

In between the property is accessed from a view controller like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] retain];
WAHolodeckRequestSigner.apiId = appDelegate.apiId;
[appDelegate release];
```

But when I run the analyzer, he complains

> "potential leak of an
>   object", "Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in
>   this execution path and has a retain count of +1"

Comment: Is the analyzer pointing at the `_apiId` ivar?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: You need to show the exact code that's getting the analyzer error. There are almost always multiple steps through the code in the analyzer result. You have to show those, too. Finally, string properties should almost always be `copy`, not just `retain`. Otherwise, you could get outside code modifying your object's state behind its back.

Comment: @KenThomases I added more code to clarify

Comment: Showa screenshot of the execution path.

Comment: `self.apiId = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";`. Is that your real code?

Comment: *"The project is using Manual Reference Counting."*. - Why? Change that. Please. Do yourselves a giant favor and change over to ARC. It's not hard and the brief time it takes will pay for itself 100x over in saved time and effort fixing stupid memory management bugs. You can even change over one file at a time if you don't want to tackle the whole project at once.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to retain `appDelegate`. The delegate is retained by the `UIApplication` object. So unless you plan to replace that object within this block of code, there's no reason to `retain` and `release` it. Also, if you do need to retain it, use `retain` + `autorelease` when you get the reference ... that's what autorelease pools are for.